# InfoPath form has connection to SQL server, but form data is not being submitted and stored in db table?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server, infopath-rules, sql-query

I am created one submit rule which it has the action 1) query using a data connection: Main connection 2) set a field's value @fullname = 1.

I need help creating a second rule inserting all the field set data to the database.

```
SQL server = sql_server1; 
Database = database_name_here; 
table = database_table_name

concat("ExecuteSqlQuery /dsname=SQL /sql=set database_name_here off INSERT INTO [dbo].[database_table_name] ([ID],[Full Name]) VALUES (@ID, @fullName)")
```

HELP IS APPRECIATED!

Answer (score 0):

This is not really the best approach to post the data to SQL via infopath. I would suggest to follow the below

1. create a web service which internally connects to SQL server. Consume that service and post to the service in infopath.

[reference link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2007/01/29/submitting-to-a-database-via-web-services-in-infopath-forms-services.aspx)

2. Create a BCS external list and then modify the forms using infopath with required rules and submit the data. Refer [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554886(v=office.14).aspx)